# Same css font properties but different display in angularjs view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-view

I've a big problem and apparently nobody seems to have encountered this problem yet. 
I have been modifying my website which uses AngularJS to use views instead of charging the whole page everytime. Now I've made slight modifications to the css at the same time, but now I have a very strange difference (I'm using the same browser for the two displays, google chrome) between the two views.
I also included in the image jquery calls to show that the css font-related properties of the two images are the same. The 'h4' element that I test with jQuery is the middle one, "Titre", but the two other elements should also be displayed the same. Left view is whithout angularjs ng-view and right view is in the angularjs ng-view
[image: font display differences with the same font properties]
Thanks for any help, I have to say that I have no idea about what might cause this behavior.

Comment: can you provide a plunker for this?

Comment: using inspect element in `chrome` you can find out if any fonts are being applied by the user agent or by other css rules which might override the css rule for the `h4` element

Comment: Ah I found out the solution while creating the plunker.. This was coming from an @_font-face in a css file which was overriding the normal font in one case and the URL for the font was not correct. I wish the developer tools would also show that 'property' @_font-face in the console...